# Automatic Testing of socket using jasmine

Tags: node.js, sockets, testing, jasmine

Currently, I am using frisby Testing framework in my project to test API End-points which using jasmine-node. now I am using sockets.io in my project for notification between client/server and it is working fine. How can I test socket.io integration/implementation with jasmine-node (without using mocha)? Any suggestion will be appreciated.